# Reversing Computation Through Externalization

Tags: java, serialization, reflection

I have a distinct feeling I'm getting way over my head again. A few months ago I built a system that search through code and made modifications using reflection. This worked nicely, now I'm trying to rebuild the system and generalise some aspects of it a little. One thing I'd like to do is be agnostic to the changes that might have gone on in the most recent bit of computation.

So, for instance, let's say I'm executing a Mario program and we press a button. The game's state has changed, but we don't know how. I want to reverse this effect so I can go back in time and press a different button. My plan is:

- Externalize all the game classes that may have had some effect applied to them. Store the value of all non-final fields, including static values.
- Write out all game objects using extern.
- Make the change.
- Write out all game objects using extern (in case we want to jump back to this state later)
- Read the pre-change state back in again.

On the face of it, is anything going to explode in my face here? Is this a sound idea? Or will some static field/strange behaviour mess me up? For externalization I am literally planning on asking for a list of all fields via Reflection and writing them out in iteration order, so as not to miss anything.

Mods - I used the tag serialization as externalization isn't an existing tag. Hope that's ok.

EDIT - I won't need the value of local variables, or the stack or heap just yet. This may be a  consideration later though - particularly the existence/nonexistence of objects which may have been destroyed between changes.

Essentially, I need to reverse a general computation step. no idea if this is possible.

Comment: Are you also going to keep track of local variables, the current state of the stack, heap memory, and the current location of the instruction pointer before and after the button press?  There's a lot involved in the "state" of an executing program besides just objects in memory.

Comment: Good question. I'll edit above, but the short answer is no.

Comment: You better be sure that the game state is completely singleton-independent.  If there's a class called `Things` with a static variable such as `listOfActiveThings`, you're going to have a problem.

Comment: There is, indeed, exactly such things in the code.

Comment: I think your current example (a Mario game) really complicates your intent.  Can you give a very simple example of exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: The Mario example wasn't too far off. I'm effectively working on games, trying to exhaustively play them out. It's a horrendous problem, but I think it can be done. It may just be a case of "You need to limit your scope" in which case so be it.

Comment: It reminds me a little bit of the SNES emulator I used to play years ago.  It had a key to save game state, and a key to load.  You could save absolutely anywhere in the game, and reload at any time, and it would load instantly exactly the state of the game at that time.  Even in the middle of a tricky jump, you could save, reload, and try it over and over again.  I have a feeling the implementation was literally to dump the entire contents of the device's emulated memory to file.  I don't know how you could really capture a game's state by any other method than that.

Comment: That makes sense. The issue here is that I might need to store hundreds of these simultaneously, *and* the heap contains not just the game, but also the system that's modifying the game, so I can't just snapshot the whole lot.

Answer (score 1):

May be I am misreading your question but it seems to me that what you are looking for is [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).
If you already use `Spring` you can use that. Don't try to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Interesting. I used Spring once upon a time, when I was an intern. What in particular benefits me with that?

Comment: This is a good method for implementation.  But the bigger question is if this approach in the first place will reach the intended goal.

Comment: @mtrc:With `AOP` you can modify behavior of your code via aspects and `Spring` already offers this.

Comment: @mellamokb:Well he should at least be aware of his options.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Reading up on it and refreshing my memory now.